# Why does fetch row have an issue with this sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand the following error when trying to use FETCH. I'm trying to implement paging using fetch.

> Incorrect syntax near 'rows'. Expecting FROM.

```
select x.* from 
(
select empId from employees
group by empId
having count(*) > 1
) x
where empId > 0
having count(*) > 1
order by x.empId
fetch next 10 rows only
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: Do you mean `TOP 10` at the start of your query?

Comment: select @@version gives me Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 7 Enterprise 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: @Larnu, I'm trying to implement paging

Comment: Then where if your `OFFSET` @Rod? You need an `OFFSET` prior to `FETCH NEXT`.

Comment: Also, however, that query isn't going to run, `empid` isn't contained in a `GROUP BY` in your outer query.

Comment: For some strange reason MS SQL Server requires the OFFSET clause if FETCH FIRST is used.

Comment: Probably because, like I inferred above, @jarlh , a `FETCH NEXT` without an `OFFSET` is just a `TOP`.

Comment: @Larnu, the ANSI SQL way!

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax in vogue you need  :

```
select empId 
from employees
where empId > 0
group by empId
having count(*) > 1
order by empId
offset 0 rows
fetch next 10 rows only;
```

Your query will never going to be execute since `empId` not present with group by clause in outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Stab in the dark, but guess you are actually after:

```
SELECT empId
FROM employees
GROUP BY empId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY empId OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```